# How to call and pass other mainscreen?

Tags: blackberry, screen, mainscreen

In class `a which extends MainScreen`, I want to call `b` class which `extends MainScreen` also.

When I pass `b.this` into a function error shown `No enclosing instance of the type b is accessible in`

Comment: can you please provide me  more information otherwise come to this room   http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-android-and-java here some one can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this is Very simple I will tell you simple way

Suppose you have two classes

1)screen1

2)screen2

screen1.java

```
public class screen1 extends MainScreen
{
   // some lines of code 
   //this is method to going to next screen in side that method 
   UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new screen2(screen1.this));
}
```

screen2.java

```
public class screen2 extends MainScreen
{
   private Screen1 screen1Object;
   // here take constructer
   public screen2(Screen1 screen1Object)
   {
      this.screen1Object=screen1Object;
   }
}
```

Here you can use that screen1Object

Comment: I mean I want to pass `screen 3` into `screen 2` when `screen 1` calling `screen 2`

Answer (score 0):

you can using this code

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeAndWait(new Runnable() 
{   
    public void run() 
    {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new NewScreen());
    }
});
```